# Тест веб приложения в GitLab Ci/Cd

Tags: java, юнит-тесты, jar, gitlab

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Есть пайплайн в GitLab по сборке и деплою веб-приложения, состоящего из двух микросервисов на java. Задача протестировать jar до сборки из них Docker образов. Я пытался просто запустить jar файл фоновым процессом в раннере GitLab, но по localhost ничего нет:

```
test:
  stage: test
  image: openjdk:8
  script:
    -  java -jar SNAPSHOT-1.0.0.jar &
    - curl http://localhost:8081/index.html
```

Есть ли какие-то другие варианты для реализации теста: просто запустить jar файл и проверить запустилась ли страничка, т.е. есть ли 200 код курлом?

UPD: 0

Проблема была в curl запросе. curl -s -o /dev/null -w "%{http_code}" http://localhost:8081/index.html Такой вариант сработал и вернул 200 код.

Comment: А вы уверенны, что ваше приложение моментально стартует и слушает порт. Обычно это небыстро, так что нужно пытаться выполнить в цикле curl какое-то время, и если не удалось, скажем, за минуту, то тогда уже выходить из цикла с ошибкой.

Comment: Ну и вопрос, что значит "по localhost ничего нет"? Какое точно сообщение получаете от curl?

Comment: Добавил `sleep 10`, результат curl -I -K : HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found

Comment: Также перед curl я смотрю список процессов, и он запущен в фоне: $ ps
PID   USER     TIME  COMMAND
    1 root      0:00 /bin/sh
    7 root      0:00 /bin/sh
    9 root      0:02 java -jar SNAPSHOT-1.0.0.jar
   21 root      0:00 ps

Comment: 404 означает, что контейнер стартовал, но путь `/index.html` неправильный. Приложению не нужны никакие параметры и т.д.? Неужели его можно стартовать с параметрами по умолчанию и оно нормально запустится?

Comment: Это не контейнер, а jar файл, который без проблем запускается и доступен по вышеуказанному url на 3 тачках - windows, centos, ubuntu. Тут проблема именно в localhost раннера.

Comment: Под контейнером я имею ввиду контейнер сервлетов (tomcat, jetty или что там у вас) или его аналог, если не используете сервлеты. Суть в том, что порт слушается, раз получаете 404, но ваше приложение внутри контейнера не отвечает по указанному пути. Нужно проверять логи приложения, очевидно оно не стартовало, как должно было бы. Или второй вариант, порт 8081 занят каким-то другим приложением вообще, и потому ваше не смогло к нему привязаться.

Comment: Судя по логам все отлично, вывод ровно такой же как и на локальной машине при нормальной работе. Может нужно использовать другой образ ранера ?